# Output command window to text file

Tags: c++

I am writing a small "tree" program in C++ with [opencscad](http://smcameron.github.io/opencscad/).  I want to get the output of the program into a .txt or .scad file so that I can compile it in OpenSCAD later.  Opencscad uses printf() to output the program, so I end up with a console window showing my program, and no way to get to it.  The program quickly becomes too big to simply copy from the console window, and Visual Studio won't let me append ">output.txt" to the "run" command.  Is there any way to either make Visual Studio output the results to a file, or to replace every printf() with some command to write to a file?

I can add the program that I'm using, but the only important bit is that it outputs a lot of text.

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to the folder containing the executable that you have built in Visual
Studio, open a console in that folder and at the console prompt enter e.g.

```
>my_prog > my_output.txt
```

Comment: I tried that, it seemed to be chopping part off if the file was long enough.

Comment: Windows does not limit the length of redirected output. What is the evidence that the output was truncated?